# replacing one navigation view with another

Tags: android, navigationview

i want to replace one menu with another, in this view i have items home,products and so on.. , while clicking on products it opens another menu containing diff products.In the below code i am trying to replace another menu,but i m getting null pointer exception, but i want know that on clicking navigation item how i can switch to another navigation view?
Can anyone suggest what to do in this situation?[I have attached logcat snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TGB0.png)

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(menuItem.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_home:
            fragmentClass = A.class;
            break;
        case R.id.menu_products:
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.getMenu().clear();
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_products);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_B:
            fragmentClass = B.class;
            break;
        case R.id.menu_C:
            fragmentClass = C.class;
            break;
        case R.id.menu_D:
            fragmentClass = d.class;
            break;
        case R.id.menu_E:
            fragmentClass = E.class;
            break;
        case R.id.menu_F:
            fragmentClass = F.class;
            break;

        default:
            fragmentClass = A.class;
    }


      try
    {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//this is line 155:    
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();

    // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // Set action bar title
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    // Close the navigation drawer
    drawer.closeDrawers();

 }
 private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView){
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
                {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: which is line `155`? I'm not sure you posted the whole code in `selectDrawerItem()`. The error seems to be related to the backstack - are you trying to add a `null` fragment?

Comment: i edited the question adding comment of line 155: @zeb

Comment: I think the code you added is not where it should be (inside  `selectDrawerItem()`).

Nonetheless I guess the problem is that `fragmentClass.newInstance()` either returns null or throws an exception (I'm betting on the latter), thus your `fragment` variable will be `null` and when you try to `replace()` it in the `FragmentManager`, it will thrown an exception. Do you see any warnings in the LogCat before the crash, coming from `e.printStackTrace()` ?

Comment: No i am not getting any warnings and yes the problem is at fragmentClass.newInstance()            W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance()' on a null object reference, the code i added is inside selectDrawerItem() but i made a mistake not pasting here...@zeb

Comment: Ok, so that error means that `fragmentClass` is `null`. Which makes sense because you're not assigning anything to it in `case R.id.menu_products`.

Comment: that is what i want to know replacing 2nd menu on clicking product so what can i do in this situation @zeb ?

Comment: Well you ARE replacing the menu, the crash is not related to that at all. Just put a `fragmentClass = FragmentYouWantToDisplay.class;` in `case R.id.menu_products:`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it works, but i don't want a fragment to be replaced the screen which was previously visited should not be replaced on clicking on product only menu should inflate any idea about this..@zeb